# Remove Welcome message and "No front page content has been created yet."

Tags: 7

The home page of my website contains `blocks` and `views` only. Hence, I want to remove both of the following message-

1. Welcome to my web
2. No front page content has been created yet.

I tried to add following code as described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1777398) but I can still see the message `Welcome to my web`

```
unset($page['content']['system_main']['default_message']);
```

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: I ran into the same in Drupal 7... this module took care of it for me. Don't know how, but pretty sure the answer above with page.tpl.php will do the trick too. https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_front_page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are displayed by the different code, hence you need to unset/remove both.

**1. Create a separate front page template:** In your theme's tempaltes folder make a duplicated of `page.tpl.php` and rename the dulpicate one as `page--front.tpl.php`. Now your all other pages will be handeled by `page.tpl.php` and the only front-page will be handeled by `page--front.tpl.php`.

**2. Edit the `page--front.tpl.php` template:** Now, as you said you are able to remove the message using the code which is in your Question, so go ahead with that.

Secondly, remove the following code from your `page--front.tpl.php`, which will remove the `Welcome......` part.

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
   <h1 id="page-title">
     <?php print $title; ?>
   </h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Little confused... Can you please have a look into [page.tpl.php](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/portfolio_zymphonies_theme/templates/page.tpl.php) ?

Comment: It is line 169.